# Number of ways to partition $\{1,2,3, \dots, N\}$ into tuples where the size of no tuple exceeds $3$.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, integer-partitions

While it seems to me that the general answer is not going to be a neat formula, I really only need this for $N=4$ and $N=5$. I'm getting $61$ and $321$ respectively, but I'm not sure. Please help.

Comment: Is   $N$ $=$ $ n$  ?

Comment: @zoli Yes. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: Is your $\{1\cdots N\} = \{1,2,3,\cdots,N\}$ or other thing?

Comment: @pisco125 The same.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by _partition into tuple_ in this context, can you give some example?

Comment: You should say what combinatorial objects you mean: combinations, integer partitions, integer compositions, set partitions or set compositions.